# Extend Background of Drop-down Menu to Full Width of Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm attempting to create a mega menu that displays all contents of each individual list item. You can think of it as a simple/traditional drop-down, however all child items are visible when hovered.

I've got them all to display, however trying to figure out how to extend the drop-down menu background to extend the full width of the browser.

I tried extending the last submenu, but that didn't work out too well.

[Codepen for full code](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/EBrodo?editors=1111a)

Here's snippets:

HTML

```
<nav class="main-nav">
      <ul className="nav">
        <li>
          <a>Products</a>

          <div className="subnav-block">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a>Product A</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a>Product B</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.subnav-block {
  position: static;
  display: block;
  width: 100% !important;
  top: 54px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: gray;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0.15s;
}

.nav .subnav-block {
  float: none;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Just use `width: 100vw`

Comment: Take a look at your `<nav>` and `<ul>` elements. I believe it is one of these that is causing the issue. Since the subnav-block is inside the `<li>` element, you need to see which parent is restricting its width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add (change) styles:

```
.nav { display:flex; }
.nav > li:last-child { flex: 1; }
```

and add a virtual last menu item which will extend the width to maximum:

```
        <li>
          <a>&nbsp;</a>

          <div className="subnav-block">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a>&nbsp;</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a>&nbsp;</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following:

```css
.nav .subnav-block {
    width: 100vh;
}
```

[image]